# Should range based fog use length(vec4) or length(vec3)?

Tags: opengl, glsl, distance

I've been working on a simple range-based distance fog based on [this tutorial](http://in2gpu.com/2014/07/22/create-fog-shader/). The tutorial uses `length(viewSpace)` to get the distance of a fragment to the camera, however `viewSpace` is `vec4` meaning that the w component will factor into the length. Why is this useful? Is it even correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've spotted a bug. I think that viewSpace.w will always be 1 (assuming standard world and view matrices), so the behaviour is reasonably consistent at least.

The author of the shaders has probably just tuned his parameters with the bug in place, so it's not doing any real harm for him, and any performance impact will be negligible, but you'd be better off changing viewSpace to a vec3 IMO.

Comment: That's what I suspected, thanks for clearing things up!